# use-package do not bind in latex-mode-map

Tags: auctex, use-package, bind-key.el

this is a part of my init file

> ```
> (use-package tex-site
>  :ensure auctex
>  :mode
>    ("\\.tex\\'" . latex-mode)
>  :bind
>    (:map LaTeX-mode-map
>      ("<f5> <f5>" . TeX-command-save-buffer-and-run-all)))
>  :init
>   (defun TeX-command-save-buffer-and-run-all ()
>   "Save the buffer and run TeX-command-run-all"
>   (interactive)
>   (let (TeX-save-query) (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file)))
>   (TeX-command-run-all nil))
> ```

None binding is done in latex-mode, but if I evaluate this after a tex file has been opened,it  works fine.

I tried (find-file "mwe.tex) in my init file, and the bindings works.
I suppose there is a smarter way to make this init file work like I want it to

Comment: Have you tried `latex` instead of `tex-site`?

Comment: I did, and plenty others. for the moment, I just add (find-file "foo.tex")(kill-buffer "foo.tex") for it work. I'm just asking for a smarter solution.

Comment: It is clear that your current approach cannot work since `tex-site.el` does not define `LaTeX-mode-map`.
`LaTeX-mode-map` is defined in `latex.el` and `tex-site.el` does not load `latex.el`.

From that point of view [Omar's suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50890/use-package-do-not-bind-in-latex-mode-map#comment78398_50890) to replace `tex-site` with `latex` appears to be right.

Comment: I think you  can replace the loading and killing of `foo.tex` with `(require 'latex)`. That is the thing that might be relevant for your problem.

Comment: My apologize, Omar was right, replacing tex-site by latex fixed the issue.
I need learning a lot of skills in emacs-lisp...